# Цикл пропускает первое значение

Tags: php, mysql

http://pastebin.com/N8JMUuw4

Цикл пропускает первое значение, в чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот здесь:

```
 $result = mysql_fetch_array($query); //сдвигаем указатель на один
 print_r($result);
 while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) //начинаем со второго(первого)....
```

чтобы "починить"

```
 $result = mysql_fetch_array($query); //сдвигаем указатель на один
 print_r($result);
 mysql_data_seek($query, 0); //сдвигаем указатель на начало
 while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) //начинаем с первого(нулевого)....
```

**так-же помните что расширение mysql устарело и будет удалено из php в ближайшем будущем, используйте PDO или mysqli.**

Comment: Спасибо. Проверю помечу ответ.

Comment: Нужно было подкорректировать старенький веб-интерфейс. Спасибо, все верно.